# Cannot use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` in Firestore online simulator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore security rule where `removed` field can be set to the server time stamp, to mark that a document is de-activated.

I cannot find a way to test this with the Firestore [Rules Simulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator). It allows me to build a document, but there is no `FieldValue` to select from:

[image]

This feels like a crucial feature omission, since I cannot figure out any other way to test such a rule.

Answer (score 1):

There are several cases that currently can't be simulated in the console.  If you have a feature request, you can file that with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

The best way to test your security rules is to use the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator). This lets you write code to test specific queries against rules, without the need to work with an actual Firestore instance or the console.  You should be able to test your rules that way.

Comment: I have tried the local emulator. It was problems with certain rules that took me to the simulator. They both give slightly different insights, and complement each other. Thanks for the support link!